# How can i make this map scale to all displays' sizes?

Tags: svg, display

I am trying to use a map of the world and would like it to scale with every kind of pc display's (11 inch, 13 inch, and so on). I read there and here that i must use preserveAspectRatio, but i failed in adding it to the . Can anybody help me here?

This is the beginning of my file:

```html
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   height="442.84"
   width="863.21002"
   viewBox="82.992 45.607 2528.5721 1428.3294"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.5 r10040"
   sodipodi:docname="Map.svg">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window.innerWidth and window.innerHeight to provide viewBox and svg width and height.
The example below has a map of U.S. that fits nicely in any pc window.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Fit Map In Window</title>
</head>
<body style='overflow:hidden'>
<div style='position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:lightgreen'>
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  width="100%" height="100%"  >
<path fill="forestgreen" stroke="black" stroke-width=".5" id="USpath" d="M 60.074 72.607 l -0.099 0.228 l -0.491 0.472 l -0.395 0.183 l -0.462 0.062 L 58 73.461 l -0.961 -0.362 l -0.153 -0.197 l 0.169 -0.289 l 0.54 -0.274 l 0.341 -0.32 l 0.716 0.364 l 0.3 0.091 l 0.465 -0.26 l 0.215 -0.213 l 0.064 -0.366 l 0.485 -0.047 l 1.107 0.135 l 0.536 0.334 l 0.133 0.213 l -0.756 0.062 l -0.429 0 l -0.59 0.184 l -0.11 0.092 Z M 40.092 77.571 l -0.729 -0.029 l -0.097 -0.24 l 0.011 -0.3 l 0.802 -0.243 l 0.326 -0.211 l 0.593 -0.423 l 0.448 -0.137 l 0.646 -0.077 l 1.427 0.253 l 0.711 0.24 l -0.079 0.211 l -0.303 0.046 l -0.754 -0.074 l -0.496 0.031 l -1.077 0.183 l -0.269 0.226 l -1.161 0.543 Z M 38.426 77.979 l -0.515 -0.209 l -0.139 -0.285 l 0.381 -0.227 l 0.674 0.27 l 0.093 0.195 l -0.122 0.15 l -0.372 0.105 Z M 37.896 78.449 l -0.256 0.084 l -0.558 0.151 l -1.109 -0.058 l -0.387 0.135 l -0.398 0.434 l -0.31 0.15 l -0.854 -0.207 l -0.135 -0.224 l 0.497 -0.359 l 0.5 -0.315 l 0.955 -0.166 l 0.863 -0.346 l 0.39 0.089 l 0.461 0.224 l 0.341 0.409 Z M 29.628 81.29 l -0.168 -0.594 l -0.324 -0.476 l 0.839 -0.136 l 0.424 0.088 l 0.436 0.238 l -0.244 0.268 l -0.26 0.06 l -0.073 0.297 l -0.22 0.09 l -0.412 0.164 Z M 27.543 81.591 l -0.39 0.031 l -0.741 0.165 l -0.311 -0.133 l -0.088 -0.178 l 0.104 -0.119 l 0.336 -0.268 l 0.294 -0.09 l 0.584 0.222 l 0.212 0.371 Z M 54.394 157.986 l -0.559 -0.356 l -0.044 -0.884 l -0.243 -0.677 l 0.482 -0.402 l -0.035 -0.2 l -0.156 -0.26 l 0.052 -0.149 l 0.173 -0.046 l 0.354 0.158 l 0.652 0.279 l 0.593 0.425 l -0.015 0.275 l 0.238 0.046 l 0.12 0.287 l 0.306 0.149 l -0.062 0.161 L 56 156.933 l -0.172 0.204 l -0.766 0.195 l -0.374 0.23 l -0.295 0.425 Z M 23.015 59.92 l -1.613 -0.646 l -0.75 -0.205 l -0.792 -0.062 l -0.9 0.065 l -0.291 -0.095 l -0.431 -0.222 l 0.179 -0.287 l 0.516 -0.049 l 1.135 0.221 l 0.579 -0.001 l 0.543 -0.081 l 0.538 -0.001 l 0.828 0.285 l 1.725 0.362 l 0.429 0.237 l 0.046 0.111 l -0.569 -0.03 l -0.646 0.033 l -0.527 0.365 Z M 99.855 70.993 l 0.467 0.929 l -0.071 0.167 l -0.879 -0.272 l -0.621 -0.075 l 0.067 0.441 l -0.056 0.228 l -0.935 -0.607 L 97.03 71.41 l 0.396 -0.458 l 0.263 -0.153 l 0.612 -0.078 l 0.784 0.38 l 0.771 -0.108 Z M 100.975 73.606 l 0.128 0.272 l -0.086 0.273 l -0.318 0.483 l -0.559 -0.815 l -0.597 -0.909 l -0.04 -0.228 l 0.095 -0.213 l 0.407 0.029 l 0.568 0.197 l 0.402 0.91 Z M 106.858 78.207 l -1.872 -1.166 l -0.566 -0.555 l 0.01 -0.467 l -0.559 -0.843 l 0.071 -0.106 l 0.456 0.06 l 0.274 0.256 l 1.165 0.48 l 0.086 0.196 l -0.059 0.136 l -0.149 0.226 l 0.296 0.436 l 0.839 0.374 l 0.007 0.974 Z M 140.191 127.819 l -0.043 -0.094 l -0.198 -0.36 l -0.049 -0.067 l -0.032 0.042 l -0.028 0.05 l -0.04 -0.092 l 0.002 -0.664 l -0.331 -0.604 l -0.472 -0.451 l -0.661 -0.451 l -0.512 -0.197 l -0.114 -0.052 l -0.145 0.034 l 0.002 0.092 l -0.088 0.025 l -0.1 -0.042 l -0.146 -0.143 l 0.076 -0.076 l -0.073 -0.202 l -0.228 -0.252 l -0.283 -0.025 l -0.312 0.084 l -0.932 -0.336 l -0.286 -0.328 l -0.428 -0.244 l -0.383 0.042 l -0.932 -0.16 l -0.721 0.051 l -0.12 -0.185 l -0.234 -0.067 l -0.046 -0.177 l 0.094 -0.117 l -0.157 -0.504 l 0.133 -0.464 l -0.227 -0.096 l -0.127 0.008 l -0.249 -0.134 l 0 -0.101 l 0.075 -0.093 l -0.029 -0.219 l -0.347 -0.185 l -0.254 -0.286 l -0.415 -0.219 l -0.391 -0.623 l -0.202 -0.076 l -0.203 -0.311 l -0.409 -0.219 l -0.156 -0.529 l -0.002 -0.227 l 0.178 0.007 l 0.147 -0.164 l 0.029 -0.326 l -0.208 -0.251 l -0.192 -0.045 l -0.22 0.037 l -0.303 -0.126 l -0.535 -0.514 l 0.078 -0.21 l -0.091 -0.312 l -0.129 -0.067 l -0.044 -0.463 l 0.058 -0.152 l 0.119 -0.025 l 0.099 0.067 l 0.073 0.076 l -0.086 0.101 l 0.153 0.202 l 0.285 0.126 l 0.116 0.118 l 0.203 0.017 l -0.385 -0.564 l -0.183 -0.144 l -0.021 -0.236 l -0.184 -0.109 l -0.051 -0.344 l -0.13 0.006 l -0.011 0.144 l 0.048 0.446 l -0.093 0.017 l -0.293 -0.194 l -0.119 0.042 l -0.516 -0.404 l -0.136 -0.363 l -0.377 -0.514 l -0.531 -0.379 l -0.624 -0.583 l -0.123 -0.142 l 0.114 -0.101 l -0.327 -0.751 l 0.161 -0.43 l -0.254 -0.479 l -0.22 -0.355 l -0.738 -0.782 l -0.104 -0.299 l 0.099 -0.627 l 0.252 -0.628 l 0.166 -0.357 l 0.059 -0.856 l -0.215 -0.785 l -0.692 -1.486 l -0.153 -0.916 l 0.096 -0.287 l 0.231 -0.244 l 0.402 -0.201 l 0.365 -0.717 l -0.365 -0.573 l -0.066 -0.33 l 0.424 -1.593 l 0.153 -0.575 l 0.061 -0.634 l 0.091 -0.778 l 0.019 -0.179 l -0.153 -0.16 l 0.08 -0.231 l -0.103 -0.167 l 0.157 -0.077 l -0.03 -0.186 l -0.046 -0.186 l -0.031 -0.103 l -0.004 -0.058 l 0.322 0.096 l 0.209 -0.019 l 0.062 -0.097 l -0.211 0.006 l -0.614 -0.122 l 0.062 -0.707 l -0.103 -0.328 l 0.017 -0.277 l 0.587 -0.225 l -0.345 -0.019 l -0.16 -0.142 h -0.129 l -0.053 0.045 l 0.042 0.116 l -0.12 0.052 l -0.133 -0.979 l -0.927 -1.463 l -0.017 -0.465 l 0.129 -0.131 l 0.544 0.086 l 0.632 0.217 l 0.785 0.114 l 0.641 0.028 l 0.546 -0.044 l 0.415 0.086 l 0.547 0.318 l 0.039 0.435 l -0.42 0.407 l -0.413 0.347 l 0.532 0.146 l 0.184 0.188 l 0.251 0.169 l 0.029 -0.228 l 0.161 -0.232 l 0.393 -0.305 l 0.21 -0.581 l 0.102 -0.465 l -0.064 -0.421 l -0.356 -0.958 l -0.158 -0.305 l -0.655 -0.516 l 0.194 0.013 l 2.579 0.001 l 1.335 0.022 l 4.588 -0.025 l 3.938 0.008 l 2.87 -0.001 l 1.687 0.006 l 5.117 -0.028 l 0.74 0.011 l 4.13 0.021 l 1.089 -0.035 l 3.821 0.023 l 0.875 -0.005 l 3.617 -0.004 l 4.84 0.018 l 0.601 -0.003 l 2.935 0.014 l 2.131 -0.012 l 2.781 0.029 l 2.915 -0.016 l 2.105 0.003 l 1.348 -0.007 l 2.798 0.029 l 2.687 -0.029 l 0.68 0.003 l -0.387 -0.588 l -0.131 -0.347 l 0.501 -0.036 l 0.896 0.748 l 0.279 0.371 l 0.468 0.46 l 0.833 0.451 l 0.518 -0.076 l 1.425 0.208 l 0.02 0.185 l 0.271 -0.012 l 0.338 0.48 l 0.16 -0.247 l 0.502 0.013 l 0.241 0.271 l 0.469 0.086 l 0.064 0.185 l 0.506 0.098 l 0.573 -0.141 l 0.219 -0.06 l 0.412 -0.191 l 0.373 -0.075 l 0.028 0.282 l 0.197 0.116 l 0.855 -0.083 l 0.474 0.041 l 0.156 0.115 l 0.196 0.144 l 0.542 -0.049 l 0.707 0.074 l 1.469 -0.592 l 0.805 -0.189 l 0.797 0.227 l 0.977 0.386 l 3.975 1.576 l 2.15 1.061 l 0.101 0.429 l 0.46 0.465 l 0.628 -0.024 l 0.178 0.135 l 0.184 0.294 l 0.916 0.181 l 0.307 0.235 l -0.11 0.318 l 0.26 0.33 l 2.529 1.05 l 0.876 3.16 l 0.054 0.545 l -0.028 0.746 l -0.377 0.576 l -0.294 0.544 l -0.264 0.433 l -0.414 0.294 l -0.707 0.525 l -0.044 0.218 l 0.012 0.33 l 0.371 0.427 l 0.497 0.169 l 0.573 0.068 l 0.524 -0.117 l 0.925 -0.506 l 0.939 -0.478 l 0.88 -0.262 l 0.919 -0.062 l 0.944 -0.163 l 1.464 -0.452 l 0.875 -0.427 l -0.047 -0.362 l -0.16 -0.471 l -0.018 -0.319 l 0.162 -0.375 l 0.47 -0.203 l 0.93 -0.091 l 1.123 0.01 l 1.305 0.138 l 1.156 -0.197 l 0.44 -0.275 l 0.163 -0.512 l 0.146 -0.434 l 0.545 -0.164 l 1.754 -0.814 l 0.534 -0.305 l 0.968 -0.523 l 1.76 -0.009 l 2.508 0.029 l 1.855 0.004 l 1.093 0.095 l 0.174 -0.375 l 0.363 -0.435 l 0.402 -0.06 l 1.161 0.124 l 1.139 -1.45 l 1.139 -2.22 l 0.514 -0.626 l 0.632 -0.526 l 0.273 0.085 l 0.505 0.36 l 0.381 0.085 l 0.41 -0.176 l 0.771 0.025 l 0.488 0.288 l 0.174 0.274 l 0.31 2.819 l -0.077 0.229 l 0.606 0.231 h 0.224 l 0.042 0.154 l -0.143 0.069 l 0.02 0.256 l -0.192 0.077 l 0.16 0.291 l 0.188 -0.153 l 0.349 0.495 l -0.268 0.281 l 0.299 -0.04 l 0.171 0.093 l -0.511 0.374 l -0.509 0.093 l -0.297 -0.12 l -0.013 0.253 l -0.138 0.067 l -0.077 -0.107 l -0.231 -0.08 l -0.277 0.133 l -0.101 0.28 l -0.171 -0.013 l -0.15 0.16 l -0.175 -0.347 l -0.746 0.28 l -0.204 -0.093 l 0.12 0.413 l -0.666 -0.213 l 0.199 -0.48 l -0.149 -0.04 l -0.364 0.52 l -0.332 0.56 l -0.342 0.333 l -0.324 -0.227 l -0.249 0.439 l -0.346 -0.08 l 0.122 -0.307 l -0.325 0.253 l 0.165 0.16 l -0.326 0.293 l -0.318 -0.133 l 0.105 -0.226 l -0.654 0.253 l 0.065 0.359 l -0.264 0.04 l -0.161 0.373 l -0.352 0.106 l -0.333 0.679 l -0.404 0.505 l 0.173 0.146 l 0.068 0.212 l 0.168 0.053 l 0.083 -0.08 l 0.169 0.013 l -0.122 0.146 l -0.547 0.106 l 0.053 0.093 l -0.392 0.292 l -0.068 0.159 l 0.337 0.027 l 0.282 0.093 l 0.599 0.704 l 0.055 0.398 l 0.399 0.106 l 0.691 -0.239 l -0.022 -0.186 l -0.14 -0.027 l -0.254 -0.279 l -0.097 -0.04 l -0.009 -0.066 h 0.196 l 0.23 0.133 l 0.218 0.358 l 0.031 0.425 l -1.599 0.292 l -0.032 -0.385 l -0.124 -0.066 l -0.109 0.226 l -0.164 0.04 l -0.03 0.093 l -0.105 -0.106 l -0.159 0.266 l -0.164 0.04 l -0.294 0.04 l -0.045 -0.332 l 0.198 -0.332 l -0.443 0.119 l -0.154 -0.146 l -0.082 0.252 l -0.087 0.664 l -1.429 0.132 l -1.694 0.159 l -1.182 0.345 l -0.787 0.358 l -0.097 0.212 l -0.32 0.053 l -0.144 0.172 l -0.032 -0.04 l 0.308 -0.756 l 0.024 -0.106 l -0.071 0.027 l -0.41 0.994 l -0.079 -0.08 l -0.406 0.292 l 0.218 0.318 l 0.553 0.093 l -0.46 1.515 l -0.302 0.429 l -0.259 -0.092 l 0.043 0.251 l -0.062 0.185 l -0.237 0.145 l -0.462 0.501 l -0.292 0.304 l -0.167 0.026 l -0.075 -0.119 l 0.177 -0.31 l -0.113 -0.178 l -0.43 0.013 l -0.447 -0.343 l -0.148 -0.053 l -0.329 -0.541 l 0.315 -0.257 l 0.151 -0.245 l -0.271 0.119 l -0.362 0.37 l 0.489 0.845 l 0.033 0.356 l 0.387 0.581 l 0.28 0.066 l 0.104 0.765 l -0.101 0.238 l -0.151 0.23 l -0.125 -0.013 l -0.487 0.666 l -0.396 0.798 l 0.034 0.053 l -0.13 0.132 l -0.107 -0.125 l -0.374 0.725 l 0.026 0.125 l -0.226 0.04 l -0.137 -0.263 l 0.342 -0.864 l 0.195 -0.29 l 0.247 -0.119 l 0.061 -0.237 l -0.093 -0.059 l -0.374 0.119 l 0.226 -0.383 l -0.218 0.04 l -0.176 -0.093 l 0.012 -0.191 l 0.242 -0.04 l -0.077 -0.33 l -0.439 0.296 l -0.241 -0.204 l -0.157 0.053 l -0.23 -0.396 l 0.355 -0.171 l 0.357 -0.053 l -0.005 -0.06 l -0.604 -0.316 l -0.092 0.165 h -0.072 l 0.107 -0.323 l 0.089 -0.02 l 0.21 0.159 l 0.131 -0.06 l -0.098 -0.224 l -0.353 -0.066 l -0.065 -0.112 l 0.096 -0.112 l 0.336 0.02 l 0.193 -0.284 l -0.281 0.046 l -0.158 -0.059 l 0.241 -0.37 l 0.652 -0.152 l -0.328 -0.06 l 0.146 -0.409 l -0.28 0.093 l -0.096 0.132 l 0.11 0.079 l -0.315 0.191 l -0.035 -0.224 l -0.093 0.053 l 0.051 0.224 l -0.081 0.086 l -0.051 -0.158 l -0.097 -0.066 l -0.103 0.416 l -0.447 -0.079 l 0.402 0.501 l -0.294 0.666 l 0.07 0.237 l 0.272 0.488 l -0.055 0.139 l -0.466 -0.317 l -0.1 -0.211 l 0.026 0.205 l 0.174 0.218 l 0.421 0.237 l 0.132 0.508 l -0.631 -0.402 l -0.354 -0.007 l -0.118 -0.283 l -0.155 -0.053 l 0.066 0.25 l -0.541 -0.323 l -0.33 0.04 l 0.015 -0.29 l 0.427 -0.323 l -0.428 0.079 l -0.19 0.468 l 0.204 0.231 l 0.457 0.046 l 0.202 0.25 l 0.954 0.297 l -0.047 0.092 l 0.554 0.165 l 0.158 0.132 l -0.22 0.468 l -0.227 0.06 l -1.042 -0.804 l 0.708 0.811 l 0.626 0.171 l -0.248 0.092 l 0.323 0.079 l -0.045 0.079 l 0.061 0.06 l -0.034 0.25 l -0.312 -0.191 l -0.071 0.073 l 0.104 0.211 l -0.216 0.02 l -0.656 -0.56 l -0.023 0.026 l 0.419 0.475 l 0.309 0.158 l 0.182 -0.026 l 0.191 0.21 l 0.018 0.31 l -0.298 0.059 l -0.492 -0.534 l -0.474 -0.198 l -0.199 0.16 l 0.046 0.044 l 0.44 0.145 l 0.488 0.382 l -0.047 0.237 l 0.442 -0.033 l 0.031 -0.119 l 0.748 0.119 l 0.151 0.382 l 0.406 1.212 l 0.448 0.803 l -0.14 -0.092 l -0.262 -0.349 l -0.059 -0.132 l -0.359 -1.172 l -0.147 -0.277 l -0.056 0.31 h 0.135 l 0.034 0.198 l -0.292 -0.066 l 0.173 0.283 l 0.144 0.099 l 0.228 0.58 l -0.144 -0.053 l -0.211 -0.382 l 0.002 0.224 l -0.52 -0.303 l -0.06 0.059 l 0.266 0.303 l -0.247 0.119 l -0.526 -0.204 l 0.225 0.204 l -0.375 0.211 l -0.173 -0.02 l -0.251 -0.21 l -0.024 -0.217 l 0.083 -0.158 l -0.081 -0.053 l -0.091 0.204 l 0.044 0.23 l 0.116 0.211 l -0.107 0.158 l 0.894 0.02 l 0.571 -0.145 l 0.125 0.165 l -0.113 0.191 l -0.072 0.369 l 0.14 0.066 l 0.092 -0.257 l 0.135 -0.369 l 0.18 -0.105 l 0.266 0.31 l 0.047 0.296 l -0.166 0.25 l -0.163 -0.013 l -0.063 -0.099 l -0.316 0.474 l -0.254 0.197 l -0.483 -0.053 l -0.203 -0.065 l -0.147 -0.066 l -0.136 -0.245 l -0.151 0.014 l 0.141 0.244 l -0.075 0.013 l -0.538 -0.125 l -0.436 -0.151 l 0.162 0.185 l 0.269 0.026 l 0.833 0.335 l -0.034 0.119 l -0.396 0.145 l 0.247 0.007 l -0.19 0.25 l -0.281 0.138 h -0.149 l -0.481 -0.375 l 0.242 0.395 l 0.43 0.164 l 0.302 -0.171 l 0.292 0.026 l 0.11 -0.204 l 0.04 0.178 l 0.217 0.04 l 0.048 0.079 l -0.428 0.322 l -0.013 0.085 l -0.261 0.072 l -1.498 0.214 l -0.865 0.895 l -0.487 0.609 l -0.13 0.127 l -0.935 0.143 l -0.528 0.128 l -0.617 0.241 l -0.678 0.539 l -0.225 0.424 l -0.096 0.354 l -0.819 0.694 l -0.693 0.383 l -0.429 0.199 l -0.797 0.086 l -0.35 0.58 l -0.177 0.198 l -0.809 1.125 l -0.273 0.781 l -0.459 1.249 l 0.236 1.455 l 0.387 0.925 l 0.456 0.873 l 0.934 1.562 l 0.352 1.746 l 0.486 1.194 l -0.075 0.092 l 0.287 0.276 l 0.123 0.333 l 0.062 0.827 l -0.301 1.536 l -0.064 0.278 l -0.31 0.415 l 0.108 0.424 l -0.02 0.252 l -0.393 0.551 l -0.017 -0.092 l 0.129 -0.241 l -0.025 -0.138 l -0.256 0.035 l -0.38 0.137 l -0.291 -0.126 l -0.509 0.138 l -0.12 -0.329 l 0.014 -0.233 l -0.567 -1.068 l -0.764 -0.138 l -0.204 -0.352 l -0.113 -0.819 l -0.423 -0.229 l -0.144 -0.702 l -0.373 0.093 l -0.608 -1.08 l -0.375 -0.482 h 0.296 l 0.375 -0.438 l 0.048 -0.226 l -0.167 -0.226 l -0.471 0.407 l -0.277 -0.208 l 0.126 -0.573 l 0.147 -0.758 l 0.158 -1.043 l -0.293 -0.452 l -0.258 -0.169 l -0.496 -0.126 l -0.832 -0.987 l -0.875 -0.804 l -0.528 -0.168 l -0.43 0.072 l -0.536 0.298 l -0.456 0.354 l -1.202 0.299 l -0.273 -0.213 l -0.131 -0.62 l -0.253 -0.254 l -0.264 -0.113 l -0.752 -0.069 l -0.516 -0.296 l -0.22 -0.233 l -0.504 0.138 l -1.052 0.115 l -0.653 -0.184 l -0.047 0.298 l -0.64 0.099 h -0.183 l -0.578 -0.926 l -0.238 0.781 l -0.447 -0.135 l -0.65 0.001 l -1.328 -0.04 l -0.672 0.439 l -0.39 0.055 l -1 -0.459 l -0.096 0.009 l -0.142 0.014 l -0.362 0.528 l 0.201 0.229 h 0.303 h 0.211 l 0.537 -0.207 l 0.406 0.092 l 0.676 0.482 l -0.68 0.373 l 0.02 0.254 l 0.263 0.353 l 0.593 0.146 l 0.229 0.217 l 0.35 0.334 l -0.533 0.136 l -0.503 -0.084 l -0.276 -0.419 l -0.79 -0.271 l -0.224 -0.211 l -0.265 -0.056 l -0.013 0.02 l -0.209 0.32 l 0.209 0.154 l 0.248 0.183 l -0.248 0.179 l -0.069 0.05 l -0.447 -0.459 l -0.476 0.192 l -0.287 0.291 l -1.025 -0.472 l -0.419 -0.494 l -1.16 -0.642 l -0.615 0.066 l 0.554 0.393 l -0.307 0.187 l -1.17 -0.083 l -0.886 -0.252 l -0.896 -0.168 l -1.547 0.173 l -0.632 0.328 l -0.392 -0.015 l -0.433 -0.031 l -0.135 -0.49 l -0.333 0.057 l -0.112 0.184 l 0.474 0.731 l -0.877 0.64 l -0.808 0.577 l -0.915 0.317 l -0.419 0.043 l -0.414 -0.056 l -0.728 -0.111 l -0.126 0.198 l 0.437 0.437 l -0.239 0.396 l -0.327 0.199 l -0.631 0.114 l -0.737 0.27 l -0.268 0.17 l 0.558 0.352 l 0.111 0.169 l -0.659 0.694 l -0.154 0.297 l -0.012 0.848 l 0.144 0.636 l 0.271 0.762 l 0.425 0.903 l -0.347 -0.119 l -0.816 -0.377 l -0.296 0.001 l -0.416 0.116 l -0.264 -0.069 l -1.029 -0.56 l -0.921 -0.32 l -0.375 -0.365 l -0.336 -0.592 l -0.332 -0.932 l -0.078 -0.467 l -0.268 -0.253 l -0.657 -0.576 l -0.845 -1.042 l -0.744 -1.227 l -0.663 -1.029 l -0.363 -0.366 l -0.412 -0.252 l -0.783 -0.321 l -0.475 -0.082 l -0.643 0.018 l -0.468 0.201 l -0.576 0.541 l -0.418 0.413 l -0.283 0.37 l -0.416 0.158 l -0.501 -0.011 l -0.337 -0.069 l -1.104 -0.503 l -1.092 -0.659 l -0.445 -0.549 l -0.318 -0.847 l -0.284 -0.678 l -0.179 -0.226 l -0.708 -0.491 l -0.837 -0.519 l -0.766 -0.632 l -0.631 -0.662 l -0.209 -0.112 l -1.892 -0.046 l -1.858 -0.003 l -0.096 0.892 l -0.213 0.101 l -1.867 0.011 l -0.966 -0.037 l -1.544 -0.02 l -1.662 -0.019 l -0.338 -0.055 l -3.516 -1.112 l -2.811 -0.933 l -1.186 -0.39 l -0.267 -0.154 l -0.316 -0.31 l -2.381 0.084 l -2.367 0.155 l -0.34 0.017 Z M 49.818 152.776 l -0.122 0.086 l -0.279 0.03 l -0.111 -0.131 l -0.177 -0.005 l -0.324 0.051 l -0.304 -0.39 l -0.071 -0.263 l 0.339 -0.01 l 0.299 -0.253 l 0.188 0.218 l 0.106 0.294 l 0.223 0.096 l 0.233 0.279 Z M 52.785 154.312 l -0.155 -0.081 l -0.085 -0.356 l -0.461 -0.321 l 0.095 -0.229 l 0.143 -0.058 l 0.366 0.209 l 0.344 0.055 l 0.616 0.356 l -0.005 0.172 l -0.294 0.184 l -0.563 0.069 Z M 111.683 77.224 l -0.138 0.415 l -0.45 0.067 l -0.324 0.113 l -0.295 0.247 l -0.321 -0.137 l -0.185 -0.21 l 0.087 -0.443 l 0.086 -0.443 l -0.438 -0.675 l -0.463 -0.319 l -0.199 -0.271 l -1.281 0.055 l -0.437 0.098 l -0.153 0.161 l -0.496 0.097 l -0.019 -0.193 l -0.034 -0.432 l 0.212 -0.272 l 0.184 -0.212 l -0.378 -0.347 l -0.641 -0.438 l -0.693 -0.696 l -0.723 -0.317 l -0.453 -0.136 l 0.132 -0.35 l -0.569 -0.592 l -0.099 -0.213 l 0.371 -0.229 l -0.068 -0.122 l -0.301 -0.152 l -0.445 -0.076 l -0.392 -0.274 l -0.237 -0.259 l -0.57 -0.305 l -1 -0.411 l -0.479 -0.765 l -0.217 -0.583 l -0.367 -0.399 l -0.357 0.016 l -0.101 0.814 l 0.42 0.873 l 0.104 0.306 l -0.047 0.153 l -0.701 -0.136 l -0.272 -0.076 l -0.511 -0.504 l -0.4 -0.459 l -0.537 0.139 l -1.219 -0.228 l 1.263 0.718 l 0.032 0.214 l -1.62 0.171 l -1.093 -0.35 l -1.388 -0.948 l -0.543 -0.292 l -0.664 -0.043 l -0.079 0 l -0.933 -0.213 l -1.3 -0.536 l 0.928 -0.248 l 0.135 -0.169 L 90.8 67.129 l -0.384 -0.153 l -0.792 0.156 l -0.454 0.14 l -0.656 0.017 l -1.058 -0.06 l -1.068 -0.245 l 0.027 -0.247 l -0.148 -0.186 l -0.325 -0.108 l -0.359 0.016 l -0.47 0.202 l -1.036 0.049 l -1.465 -0.122 L 80.46 66.64 l -0.786 -0.091 l -0.248 -0.108 l -0.651 -0.387 l -0.427 -0.527 l -0.301 0.218 l -0.788 0.157 l -0.89 -0.293 l -0.234 -0.326 l -0.417 -0.139 l -0.872 -0.248 l -1.538 -0.23 l -0.817 -0.248 l -0.671 -0.342 l -0.553 0.235 l -0.675 0.079 l 0.06 0.437 l -0.193 0.062 l -0.389 0.25 l -0.249 0.405 l 1.119 0.293 l 0.174 0.294 l -0.096 0.388 l -0.428 0.449 l -0.458 0.001 l -0.804 -0.214 l -0.586 -0.061 l -0.568 0.094 l -0.978 0.603 l -1.066 0.217 l -0.936 0.448 l -1.035 0.448 l -1.095 0.109 l 0.178 -0.308 l 0.063 -0.123 l 0.72 -0.401 l -0.093 -0.385 l -0.655 -0.523 l 0.004 -0.108 L 64.1 66.19 l 0.411 -0.482 l 0.157 -0.42 l 0.736 -0.312 l 0.87 -0.235 l 1.165 -0.018 l 1.085 0.123 l 0.239 -0.156 l -1.239 -0.466 l -0.971 -0.389 l -1.043 0.049 l -0.226 0.219 l -0.449 0.095 l -0.573 0.438 l -0.865 0.375 l -1.019 0.282 L 61.553 65.9 l -0.406 0.094 l -0.298 0.14 l 0.131 0.325 l -0.177 0.526 l -0.563 0.34 l -0.564 0.078 L 59 67.544 l -0.592 0.278 l -0.681 0.601 l -0.035 0.292 l 0.38 0.168 l 0.36 0.03 l 0.667 0.106 l 0.465 0.229 l -0.075 0.184 l -0.43 0.338 l -0.625 0.2 l -0.557 0.277 l -0.423 0.398 l -0.544 0.383 l -0.675 0.093 l -1.434 0.308 l -0.678 0.397 l -1.036 0.337 l -0.7 0.367 l 0.52 0.5 l -0.1 0.167 l -1.106 0.412 l -0.897 0.153 l -0.778 0.168 L 49.51 74.19 l -1.214 0.456 L 48.1 74.828 l -0.274 0.394 l -0.753 0.439 l -1.193 0.229 l -1.234 0.184 l -0.973 -0.345 l 0.001 -0.181 l 0.332 -0.348 l 0.763 -0.273 l 0.306 -0.212 l 0.445 -0.364 l 1.171 -0.441 l 1.403 0.073 l -0.12 -0.212 l 0.02 -0.516 l 0.47 -0.304 l 0.725 -0.291 l 0.754 -0.366 l 0.266 -0.214 l 0.002 -0.731 l 0.246 -0.749 l 0.693 -0.49 l 0.194 -0.398 l 0.034 -0.412 l -0.633 0.122 l -1.251 0.186 l -0.676 -0.029 l -0.5 -0.597 l -0.266 0.062 l -0.613 0.216 l -0.136 0.23 l 0.239 0.352 l 0.021 0.352 l -0.169 0.046 L 47 70.115 l -0.567 -0.32 l -0.487 -0.397 l -0.509 -0.291 l -0.56 -0.03 l -0.812 -0.106 l -0.91 0.094 l 0.028 0.138 l -0.644 0.338 l -1.175 0.14 l -0.649 -0.09 l -0.064 -0.123 l -0.082 -0.107 l -0.125 -1.028 l 0.3 -0.508 l -0.142 -0.431 l -0.864 -1.002 l -1.43 0.437 l -0.738 0.078 l -0.406 0.202 l -1.091 0.094 l -0.4 -0.23 l -0.394 -0.355 l -0.466 -0.325 l -1.007 -0.463 l -0.179 -0.28 l 0.292 -0.171 l 0.337 -0.437 l 0.704 0.139 l 1.312 0.309 l 0.69 0.03 l 0.238 -0.234 l -0.375 -0.482 l -0.458 -0.264 l -0.363 0 l -0.541 0.22 l -0.528 -0.015 l -1.342 -0.513 l -0.623 -0.186 l -0.197 0.016 l -0.858 -0.029 l -0.024 -0.078 l -0.623 -0.985 l 0.79 -0.19 l 0.071 -0.456 l 0.495 -0.221 l 0.102 -0.299 l 0.227 -0.347 l 0.893 -0.491 l 0.337 -0.38 l 0.386 -0.301 l 0.527 -0.476 l 0.39 -0.175 l 0.719 0.109 l 0.98 0.268 l 0.485 0.094 l 0.752 -0.144 l 0.427 -0.254 l 0.675 -0.429 l 1.252 -0.257 l 0.774 -0.033 l 0.955 -0.049 l 0.354 -0.175 l 0.187 -0.478 l -0.259 -0.669 l -0.814 -0.686 l 0.026 -0.096 l 0.927 -0.034 l 0.343 -0.256 l -0.25 -0.384 l -0.497 -0.256 l -0.367 -0.08 l -1.88 0.389 L 39.33 56.53 l -0.534 0.289 l -0.496 0.065 l -1.907 -0.333 l -0.848 -0.031 L 34.8 56.49 l -1.27 0.162 l -1.265 -0.029 l -1.349 -0.174 l -0.53 -0.207 l -0.183 -0.788 l 0.144 -0.146 l 0.636 -0.033 l 1.008 -0.002 l 0.446 -0.179 l -1.057 -0.241 l -1.912 -0.304 L 28.13 54.31 l -1.285 -0.208 l 0.219 -0.114 l 0.781 -0.262 l 1.568 -0.214 l 1.325 -0.328 l 0.958 -0.214 l 1.058 -0.361 l 0.953 -0.23 l 1.399 -0.281 l 1.513 0.128 l -0.158 0.523 l 0.023 0.277 l 1.051 0.161 l 1.359 0.095 l 1.074 -0.019 l 0.657 -0.099 l 0.784 -0.246 l 0.55 -0.295 l 0.262 -0.083 l 0.752 0.064 l 0.751 0.113 l 1.021 -0.051 l 0.2 -0.327 l 0.007 -0.18 l -0.689 -0.064 l -1.946 -0.292 l -1.283 -0.047 l -0.312 -0.755 l -1.473 -0.162 l -0.96 -0.031 l -1.573 -0.096 l -0.194 -0.511 l -0.484 -0.312 l -1.042 -0.461 l -0.512 -0.148 l -2.66 -0.659 l -2.008 -0.545 l 0.317 -0.167 l 0.812 -0.402 l 0.086 -0.485 l 2.136 -0.054 l 0.99 -0.069 l 1.829 -0.288 l 0.784 -0.354 l 0.452 -0.623 l 0.788 -0.575 l 0.616 -0.525 l 0.818 -0.41 l 0.742 -0.224 l 1.066 -0.104 l 1.133 -0.241 l 1.047 -0.036 l 1.804 0.065 l 0.146 -0.188 l -0.156 -0.205 L 44.47 42.83 l 0.018 -0.206 l 1.936 -0.089 l 1.143 0.032 l 0.974 -0.054 l 1.344 -0.14 l 1.098 -0.416 l 0.918 -0.417 l 0.957 -0.019 l 0.282 0.051 l 0.675 0.241 l 0.156 0.172 l -0.383 0.139 l 0.017 0.344 l 1.049 0.136 l 0.424 0.034 l 0.536 -0.293 l 0.297 -0.208 l 1.419 0.187 l 1.534 0.049 l 1.062 0.049 l 0.715 0.033 l 0.711 0.257 l 0.359 0.274 l 0.783 0.358 l 0.494 0.085 l 0.421 -0.086 l 1.292 0.117 l 1.124 0.015 l 1.556 -0.054 l 1.449 -0.088 l 1.213 0.1 l 1.377 0.254 l 0.883 0.118 l 3.424 0.13 l 1.279 0.168 l 0.743 0.169 l 2.027 -0.038 l 2.339 -0.141 l 1.123 0.236 l 2.441 0.791 l 1.206 0.301 l 0.227 0.008 l 0.102 0.483 l -0.003 2.855 l 0.039 2.259 l 0.052 2.335 l 0.129 2.796 l -0.026 2.183 l -0.043 4.334 l 0.026 2.167 l 0.089 1.046 l 0.196 0.279 l 0.84 0.074 l 2.424 -0.122 l 0.739 0.059 l 0.332 0.388 l 0.173 0.387 l 0.348 0.292 l 2.162 1.318 l 0.945 0.673 l 0.238 -0.325 l 0.848 -0.205 l 1.225 -0.67 l 0.731 -0.498 l 0.495 -0.126 l 0.832 0.073 l 0.316 0.199 l 0.371 0.492 l 0.35 0.322 l 2.048 1.175 l 0.814 0.58 l 1.769 1.768 l 1.67 1.882 l 0.512 0.393 l 0.189 0.029 l 0.98 0.314 l 2.025 0.763 l 0.402 0.255 l -0.163 0.788 l 0.393 0.777 Z" name="United States"></path>
</svg>
</div>
<script>
//--onload, onresize----
function sizeFull()
{
 var mySVG=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
   var svgW=window.innerWidth
 var svgH=window.innerHeight
    var bb=mySVG.getBBox()
 var bbx=bb.x
 var bby=bb.y
 var bbw=bb.width
 var bbh=bb.height

    mySVG.setAttribute("viewBox",bbx+" "+bby+" "+bbw+" "+bbh )
    mySVG.setAttribute("width",svgW)
    mySVG.setAttribute("height",svgH)
}
sizeFull(); //---init window---
document.addEventListener("onload",sizeFull(),false)
window.onresize=sizeFull
</script>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Francis Hemsher. I have one more request: being I very new to this, i am trying to keep it as simple as it could be. Is it possible to do it without a function?

Comment: @pablobs88 I just don't know how to do it without Javascript. If you care to provide a link to your map's svg file, I could add the javascript to a web page and see what happens.

Comment: Hammer I would really gladly do it, but it looks like i am not allowed to add the whole code, which is very large. Thank you very much in any case!